# How to create ios native look like infinite image grid with multiple columns

Tags: codenameone

Is there a way of creating ios native look like image grid, like e.g. in pinterest or beyond-shopping, with scrolling that doesn't jitter, lag, or stuck for couple of milliseconds? I've spent some time setting up InfiniteContainer, and try other approaches, used various kinds of layouts, but on ios it's still not looking as it should. Especialy on devices like new IPads PRO, this should be pretty smooth, but it's not...

Comment: This is absolutely possible with Cn1.  It is best to share what you have and be specific about the problems you're facing so we can suggest solutions.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the jittering happens because of IO that happens on the EDT, huge images scaled down or similar overheads (e.g. `URLImage` etc.). You need to benchmarks aggressively to understand what happens under the hood when you are using abstraction classes.

If you can create a simple test case with hardcoded images that jitters please file an issue with that so we can see what's wrong with the test case or fix a potential edge case bottleneck.